# C Question: why char actually occupies 4 bytes in memory?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, size, char

I wrote a small program to check how many bytes char occupies in my memory and it shows char actually occupies 4 bytes in memory. I understand it's mostly because of word alignment and don't see advantage of a char being only 1 byte. Why not use 4 bytes for char?

```
int main(void)
{
  int a;
  char b;
  int c;
  a = 0;
  b = 'b';
  c = 1;
  printf("%p\n",&a);
  printf("%p\n",&b);
  printf("%p\n",&c);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:
    0x7fff91a15c58
    0x7fff91a15c5f
    0x7fff91a15c54

Update:
I don't believe that malloc will allocate only 1 byte for char, even though sizeof(char) is passed as argument because, malloc contains a header will makes sure that header is word aligned. Any comments?

Update2:
If you are asked to effectively use memory without padding, is the only way is to create a special memory allocator? or is it possible to disable padding?

Comment: you could pack them with a preprocessor macro, shift + and

Comment: @Gabriel, can you explain in more detail?

Comment: How did you determine the sizeof char from the memory address?

Comment: Daniel asked the exact right question. Your question is based on a false assumption.

Comment: maybe try char* myArray = malloc(sizeof(char)*4); myArray[0] = 0; ... and then look at that?  It might be your using stack vars that is throwing the experiment off.

Comment: @Daniel, I am not intending to say that sizeof(char) is four, I am saying that what is the purpose of char if it is effectively using 4 bytes in memory due to padding?

Comment: How did you determine that the char uses 4 bytes in memory due to padding from the memory address? I count a difference of 4 between your 2 ints (compiler packed them together), and a difference of 8 between your last int and your char, determining 'sizes' from these pointers is completely undefined.

Comment: I agree that char occupies only 1 byte, but 3 bytes are used for padding right, which effectively means any time you declare a char, between two memory aligned types, the char will take 4 bytes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have int, char, int

See the image here under "Why Restrict Byte Alignment?"
http://www.eventhelix.com/realtimemantra/ByteAlignmentAndOrdering.htm

```
          Byte 0 Byte 1 Byte 2  Byte 3
0x1000               
0x1004  X0     X1     X2      X3
0x1008               
0x100C         Y0     Y1      Y2
```

If it had stored them in 4-byte, 1-byte and 4-byte form, it would have taken 2 cpu cycles to retrieve `int c` and some bit-shifting to get the actual value of c aligned properly for use as an int.

Answer (score 8):

#### Alignment

Let's look at your output for printing the addresses of a, b, and c:

> Output: 0x7fff91a15c58 0x7fff91a15c5f 0x7fff91a15c54

Notice that b isn't on the same 4 byte boundary? And that a and c are next to each other? Here is what it looks like in memory, with each row taking up 4 bytes, and the rightmost column being the 0th place:

```
| b | x | x | x | 0x5c5c
-----------------
| a | a | a | a | 0x5c58 
-----------------
| c | c | c | c | 0x5c54
```

This is the compilers way of optimizing space and keeping things word aligned. Even though your address of b is 0x5c5f, it isn't actually taking up 4 bytes. If you take your same code and add a short d, you'll see this:

```
| b | x | d | d | 0x5c5c
-----------------
| a | a | a | a | 0x5c58 
-----------------
| c | c | c | c | 0x5c54
```

Where the address of d is 0x5c5c. Shorts are going to be aligned to two bytes, so you will still have one byte of unused memory between c and d. Add in another char e, and you'll get:

```
| b | e | d | d | 0x5c5c
-----------------
| a | a | a | a | 0x5c58 
-----------------
| c | c | c | c | 0x5c54
```

Here's my code and the output. Please note that my addresses will differ slightly, but it's the least significant digit in the address that we're really concerned about anyway:

```
int main(void)
{
  int a;
  char b;
  int c;
  short d;
  char e;
  a = 0;
  b = 'b';
  c = 1;
  printf("%p\n",&a);
  printf("%p\n",&b);
  printf("%p\n",&c);
  printf("%p\n",&d);
  printf("%p\n",&e);
  return 0;
}

$ ./a.out 
0xbfa0bde8
0xbfa0bdef
0xbfa0bde4
0xbfa0bdec
0xbfa0bdee
```

#### Malloc

The man page of malloc says that it "*allocates size bytes and returns a pointer  to  the allocated memory*." It also says that it will "*return a pointer to the allocated memory, which is suitably aligned for any kind of variable*". From my testing, repeated calls to malloc(1) are returning addresses in "double word" increments, but I wouldn't count on this.

#### Caveats

My code was ran on an x86 32-bit machine. Other machines might vary slightly, and some compilers may optimize in different ways, but the ideas should hold true.

Answer (score 5):

The variable itself doesn't occupy 4 bytes of memory, it occupies 1 byte, and is then followed by 3 bytes of padding, since the next variable on the stack is an int, and therefore has to be word aligned.

In a case like the one below, you will find that the address of variable `anotherChar` is 1 byte larger than that of `b`. They are then followed by 2 bytes of padding before int `c`

```
int main(void)
{
  int a;
  char b;
  char anotherChar;
  int c;
  a = 0;
  b = 'b';
  c = 1;
  printf("%p\n",&a);
  printf("%p\n",&b);
  printf("%p\n",&anotherChar);
  printf("%p\n",&c);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming it has something to do with the packing of the variables in the stack.  I believe in your example it's forcing the integers to be 4-byte aligned.  Therefore there needs to be 3 bytes of padding before (or after) the char variable (depending on your compiler I suppose).

Comment: How does he determine from the memory address that the variable consists of 4 bytes?

Comment: That part I'm not sure on.  His variable addresses don't exactly make sense.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the final part of your question: Why not use 4 bytes for char?

Why not use 4 million bytes for `char[1000000]`?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to alignment constraints. Size of character is 1 byte only , however the integer is being aligned to a multiple of4 bytes. Character can also be followed by other characters (or say short) which might have more lenient alignment constraints. In these cases if size of char was 4 bytes indeed as you suggest, we will consume more space than necessary.